# Cloudformation - How to reference the instance-id of an EC2 instance if the instance has been created using an Auto Scaling Group and a Launch Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an EBS Volume and attach it to my EC2 instance. The instance has its own Auto Scaling Group and Launch Configuration. I want it such that if this instance becomes unhealthy and terminates, the EBS volume should automatically get attached to the new instance that is spun up by the Auto Scaling Group. The mount commands are in the Launch Configuration so that's not a problem.

Here is my code:

```
Influxdbdata1Asg:
 Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
 Properties:
  TargetGroupARNs:
    - !Ref xxxx
  VPCZoneIdentifier:
    - !GetAtt 'NetworkInfo.PrivateSubnet1Id'
  LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref yyyy
  MinSize: 1
  MaxSize: 1
  DesiredCapacity: 1
Data1:
 Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
 DeletionPolicy: Retain
 Properties:
  Size: !Ref 'DataEbsVolumeSize'
  AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt 'NetworkInfo.PrivateSubnet1Id'
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
          - data1
Attachdata1:
 Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
 Properties:
  InstanceId: !Ref ????
  VolumeId: !Ref Data1
  Device: /dev/xvdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this using:

```
Attachdata1:
 Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
 Properties:
  InstanceId: !Ref ????
  VolumeId: !Ref Data1
  Device: /dev/xvdb
```

The reason is that instance are being launched by ASG and you will not have its ideas.

Attaching must be done outside of CloudFormation, as can't know upfront what would be the instance id in future. As other answer mentions Lifecycle Hooks.

Or even better use, storage independent of ASG, such as EFS which would automatically persist between instance launches and terminations and could be mounted by multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you would specifically want to make use of [Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) which trigger whenever an instance terminates or is launched.

To do this your lifecycle hook would notify your SNS notification, which would then invoke a Lambda function. This Lambda function would perform the change, before acknowledging the lifecycle action is complete.

There is a blog post written about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-with-auto-scaling-lifecycle-hooks/).

Your question mentions CloudFormation, however this would still involve lifecycle hooks to trigger the action. You would need a CloudFormation stack with a [AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html) resource. The Lambda would need to update the "InstanceId" property in the stack to perform this change.